# Complex SQL MERGE/PIVOT Not Ordering as Desired

Tags: sql, merge, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-order-by, pivot

I have the following two tables; `ICD` created using

```
CREATE TABLE ICD ([E] VARCHAR(8), [I] VARCHAR(8));
GO
INSERT INTO ICD ([E], [I])
VALUES
    ('1', 'B1'),
    ('1', 'A1'),
    ('1', 'C23q'),
    ('1', '32Dq'),
    ('2', 'FFFq'),
    ('2', 'ERRE'),
    ('2', 'E'),
    ('3', 'WQWW'),
    ('3', 'WQ'),
    ('4', 'AAAA');
GO
```

where `O` is giving the order in which column `I` will be inserted into another table. The second table is `Episode`, this is created using

```
CREATE TABLE Episode ([EpiNum] VARCHAR(4), [SomeField] VARCHAR(4), 
                      [DX1] VARCHAR(10), [DX2] VARCHAR(10), 
                      [DX3] VARCHAR(10), [DX4] VARCHAR(10));
GO
INSERT INTO Episode ([EpiNum], [SomeField], [DX1], [DX2], [DX3], [DX4])
VALUES
    ('1', 'Test', '', '', '', ''),
    ('2', 'Test', '', '', '', ''), 
    ('3', 'Test', '', '', '', '');
GO
```

SO my goal is to insert the values from column `I` in `ICD` into the `DXn` fields depending on if there are values to insert. Bear with me; I have this working using

```
MERGE INTO [Episode] AS T 
USING (
   SELECT [EpiNum], [1], [2], [3], [4] 
   FROM 
      ( 
          SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() 
            OVER (PARTITION BY [EpiNum] ORDER BY [I]) AS rn
          FROM [ICD] 
      ) AS p
    PIVOT 
   (
      MAX([I]) 
      FOR rn IN ([1], [2], [3], [4])) AS p2
   ) AS S
ON T.[EpiNum] = S.[EpiNum] 
WHEN MATCHED THEN
   UPDATE SET [DX1] = S.[1], [DX2] = S.[2], [DX3] = S.[3], [DX4] = S.[4];
```

Which produces an `Episode` table which looks like

```
EpiNum  Test    DX1     DX2     DX3     DX4
'1'     'Test'  '32Dq'  'A1'    'B2'    'C23q'  
'2'     'Test'  'E'     'ERRE'  'FFFq'  null
'3'     'Test'  'WQ'    'WQWW'  null    null
'4'     'Test'  'AAAA'  null    null    null
```

Great! Wait... Not great, the `ORDER BY` in the PIVOT/MERGE is ruining the original order of the data. I have attempted to get around this by adding another column `O` which holds the order I want, so `ICD` is defined by

```
CREATE TABLE ICD ([E] VARCHAR(8), [I] VARCHAR(8), [O] INT);
GO
INSERT INTO ICD ([E], [I], [O])
VALUES
    ('1', 'B1.2', 1),
    ('1', 'A1.2', 2),
    ('1', 'C23q', 3),
    ('1', '32Dq', 4),
    ('2', 'FFFq', 1),
    ('2', 'ERRE', 2),
    ('3', 'WQWW', 1),
    ('4', 'AAAA', 1);
GO
```

And I am attempting to `ORDER BY` column `O` using

```
MERGE INTO [Episode] AS T 
USING (
    SELECT [E], [1], [2], [3], [4] 
    FROM 
        ( 
             SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() 
               OVER (PARTITION BY [E] ORDER BY [O]) AS rn
             FROM [ICD] 
        ) AS p
    PIVOT 
    (
       MAX([I]) 
       FOR rn IN ([1], [2], [3], [4])) AS p2
    ) AS S
ON T.[E] = S.[E] 
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET [DX1] = S.[1], [DX2] = S.[2], [DX3] = S.[3], [DX4] = S.[4];
```

But I get the following message

> The MERGE statement attempted to UPDATE or DELETE the same row more than once. This happens when a target row matches more than one source row. A MERGE statement cannot UPDATE/DELETE the same row of the target table multiple times. Refine the ON clause to ensure a target row matches at most one source row, or use the GROUP BY clause to group the source rows.

**How can I ammend the above `MERGE/PIVOT` to order correctly?**

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, your examples aren't running correctly, since you are mixing columns `[E]` and `Epinum` between the creation of the tables and the queries. But assuming that those are in fact the same columns, then your second query isn't working because you are not actually grouping on the `[E]` column. Try this instead:

```
MERGE INTO [Episode] AS T 
USING (
    SELECT [E], [1], [2], [3], [4] 
    FROM 
        ( 
             SELECT [E], [I], ROW_NUMBER() 
               OVER (PARTITION BY [E] ORDER BY [O]) AS rn
             FROM [ICD] 
        ) AS p
    PIVOT 
    (
       MAX([I]) 
       FOR rn IN ([1], [2], [3], [4])) AS p2
    ) AS S
ON T.[Epinum] = S.[E] 
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET [DX1] = S.[1], [DX2] = S.[2], [DX3] = S.[3], [DX4] = S.[4];
```

Now, I don't really understand why you are using `ROW_NUMBER()` instead of simply using the `[O]` column (the values seem the same to me), but this works either way.

Comment: This is part of a dynamic SQL query/SP. In fact the miss-match in the `EpiNum`/`E` value is an error when I was simplifying things for this question. `ROW_NUMBER()` is used as the number of `DX` type columns is dynamics and decided on the fly.

Comment: @Killercam I assumed that much. Anyway, the fixing is on not using `SELECT * FROM [ICD]` because you are repeating the values from the `[O]` column with your `ROW_NUMBER`. Use a `SELECT` that lists either one of the other (not both); that way your `PIVOT` will group correctly

Comment: Great answer, thanks for your time. Perfection... Getting a bit exasperated as meeting deadline - I am starting not to see obvious things. Thanks again for your time...